# Ловля в забродку или взабродку? Что это такое?

Tags: орфография, лексика, значение-слов, слитно-раздельно, наречия

Взабродку, забродок... И ловля где — в забродку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Что это такое?*
Вот что имеется в [энциклопедии рыбалки](https://info.wikireading.ru/218736) (П. А. Мотин).

> Ужение в забродку
> Летом при теплой погоде можно осуществлять ужение в забродку, заходя по колено или по пояс в воду. В таком случае насадку нужно забрасывать вверх по течению, и она будет передвигаться до тех пор, пока позволяют леска и удилище. В случае если поклевка не наблюдается, процедуру забрасывания повторяют.
> Следует отметить, что ужение в забродку обычно применяют на реках, где присутствует течение. Можно применять этот метод и в озерах и прудах, но эффективность его при этом будет гораздо ниже.
> Благодаря такому методу ужения можно освоить участки водоема, недоступные с берега и лодки, а процесс заброса насадки проводить проще, поскольку нет опасности запутать снасть в зарослях у берега или в ветвях деревьев.

Термин в известных мне словарях отсутствует; у автора статьи он оформлен раздельно.
Мне же думается, что это разговорное *рыболовное **наречие*** надо все-таки писать слитно: как? каким образом? — **взабродку** (сравните с написанием наречий *вброд, вразброд, втихомолку, враскачку, вприпрыжку, вразвалку*).

Правило:
наречия с предлогом **в** пишутся слитно, если существительное отдельно от **в** уже не употребляется или если между **в** и существительным нельзя вставить прилагательное или местоимение (не изменив значения существительного).

> **4.** При осуществлении подводной охоты запрещается:
> 2) использование подводных ружей с берега, с борта плавучих средств, **взабродку**...

[Слитное и раздельное написание наречий](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/679-352_pravopisanie_narechii.html#:%7E:text=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B2,%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F.)
[Проект Федерального закона "О любительском и спортивном рыболовстве"](http://www.consultant.ru/cons/cgi/online.cgi?req=doc&base=PRJ&n=153179&dst=100071#PydwA0T4DqFuSLJJ1) (ст. 10)